# Understanding autoencoder loss function

Tags: autoencoder, loss-function

I've never understood how to calculate an autoencoder loss function because the prediction has many dimensions, and I always thought that a loss function had to output a single number / scalar estimate for a given record. However, on GitHub I recently came across a [repository](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples) that has implemented an example autoencoder in TensorFlow, and the [squared error implementation](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/autoencoder.py#L82) is a lot simpler than I thought:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(y_true - y_pred, 2))
```

The TensorFlow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduce_mean) on `reduce_mean` says, among other things:

> If axis has no entries, all dimensions are reduced, and a tensor with
>   a single element is returned.

Can I conclude from all of this that the squared error of an autoencoder prediction is just the average across all of the record's dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in thinking that the squared error of an autoencoder prediction for a single example is the average of the squared error of the prediction for all dimensions. Similarly, the squared error for a whole batch of examples will be the average of the error of each example in the batch.